# mvc 4 DbUpdateException 'no default value' in Controller Create Method

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

After populating all the fields in my Create View I click Submit and get an exception in the HttpPost Create method of my Controller that states "Field 'rework_code' doesn't have a default value".  After adding a break-point above the controller I can see that the class object passed to the create method is fully populated (no null fields) so I'm confused as to why I'm getting this exception.  I'm interfacing with a MySQL database and the connection string seems to be working as the Index and Edit methods work seamlessly.

And just to be clear it's throwing the exception on db.SaveChanges()

Controller Create:

```
// POST: /DriveReworkCodes/Create
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Drive_Rework_Codes drive_rework_codes)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Drive_Rework_Codes.Add(drive_rework_codes);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(drive_rework_codes);
    }
```

Class:

```
namespace FactoryManager.Models
{
    public class Drive_Rework_Codes
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Rework Code")]
        public int Rework_Code { get; set; }
        public int Action { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at FactoryManager.Controllers.DriveReworkCodesController.Create(Drive_Rework_Codes drive_rework_codes) in c:\AAS_SDK\Projects\Training\WebApp1\FactoryManager\FactoryManager\Controllers\DriveReworkCodesController.cs:line 55
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
```

Comment: your exception is on control create not save changes, most likely your are missing a constructor with 0 parameters

Comment: ok I see controller create now, but I'm unsure what a constructor with 0 parameters would be used for?  Could you elaborate on what that is?